# Cannot create or PHP pages on Aptana

Tags: php, aptana

I installed Aptana, but could not find PHP, any idea on how to get the plugin or install the PHP features.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

[This page at Aptana's site](http://www.aptana.org/php) explains how to install the Eclipse PDT (PHP Development Tools) plugin on Aptana.

Comment: Done that, but it does not show up when I am creating a new file

Comment: Make sure you've switched to the PHP perspective after installing the plugin (Window > Open Perspective...). Then the option to create a new PHP Project or File should show up as the first thing under File > New... (Not sure which installation of Aptana you have, I'm using Aptana Studio 2.0).

Comment: I did the window->open perspective
1. Apatana web
2. debug
3. resource
4. team sync

There is nothing else, any idea on getting PHP onto it?

Answer (score 1):

You must get version 1.5 which works with PHP, I'm using it

Comment: I got the 2.2, could you suggest one for the ubuntu too